# All drop-down menus' text content change at the same time instead of updating separately

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I have three drop-down menus on my site that I created via Bootstrap.
[image]
Ideally, when a user clicks on a drop-down menu and selects one of the inner menu items, the drop-down menu should update its text content to the text content of the selected menu item.

[image]

However, for any drop-down menu, if a user clicks on a menu item, all three drop-down menus' text content update instead of only that individual drop-down menu as seen below
[image]

My current approach is that the `aria-expanded` attribute for each drop-down button changes to `true` if a drop-down is open on a button. If the `aria-expanded` value of a specific drop-down menu is `true`, then that button's text content changes to the text content of the selected menu item.

**JS**

```js
function addPlanesToDropDowns() {
  let dropdowns = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu');
  let dropDownButtonOne = document.querySelector('#dropdownMenuButtonOne');
  let dropDownButtonTwo = document.querySelector("#dropdownMenuButtonTwo");
  let dropDownButtonThree = document.querySelector("#dropdownMenuButtonThree");
  dropDownDisabledCheck();

  for (let i = 0; i < state.airplaneData.length; i++) {
    let dropDownMenuItem = document.createElement('a');
    dropDownMenuItem.classList.add('dropdown-item');
    dropDownMenuItem.href = '#';
    dropDownMenuItem.textContent = state.airplaneData[i].make + " " + state.airplaneData[i].model;

    dropDownMenuItem.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      if (dropDownButtonOne.getAttribute('aria-expanded')) {
        dropDownButtonOne.textContent = dropDownMenuItem.textContent;
        dropDownButtonOne.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
      }
      if (dropDownButtonTwo.getAttribute('aria-expanded')) {
        dropDownButtonTwo.textContent = dropDownMenuItem.textContent;
        dropDownButtonTwo.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
      }
      if (dropDownButtonThree.getAttribute('aria-expanded')) {
        dropDownButtonThree.textContent = dropDownMenuItem.textContent;
        dropDownButtonThree.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
      }
      dropDownDisabledCheck();
    });
    dropdowns.appendChild(dropDownMenuItem);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```html
       <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButtonOne" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Plane 1</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButtonTwo" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Plane 2</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButtonThree" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Plane 3</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <!-- <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Planes go here</a> -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Despite this, all three drop-down menus update with the same selected menu item text content even though I am only setting the text content on the button element with the specific ID attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fragment of code `dropDownButtonOne.getAttribute('aria-expanded')` returns a string, not a boolean value, so either `"true"` or `"false"`.

As it is a non-empty string, it always evaluates to TRUE. You need to change your condition.

You could check `if(dropDownButtonOne.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === "true")` for example.